Memory Viewer not updating values correctly
I'm working on an STM32 microcontroller project, and I'm experiencing an issue with the memory viewer in my debugging environment (using VSCode).
While the memory viewer shows the correct value for the string (e.g., "Hello, World!"), it does not reflect updates to my integer variables (a,b) after they've been incremented. However, the watch area updates correctly, showing the changes in these variables as expected.
void SystemInit(void) {}

int main()
{
  char *str = "Hello, World!";
  int a = 0;
  a++;
  a++;
  a++;
  a++;
  a++;
  int b = 0;
  b++;
  return 0;
}

Debugging Environment:

Microcontroller: STM32
IDE: VScode

What I’ve Tried:

Disabling Compiler Optimizations: I modified my Makefile to set OPT = -O0, ensuring no optimizations occur that might affect memory visibility.
Using volatile: I also tried to declare my variables as volatile to ensure they are not optimized away.

Why is the memory viewer not reflecting the updated values of my variables, even though the watch area is showing the correct values?
Are there any additional settings or steps I can take to ensure the memory viewer updates correctly?

Memory viewer when checking the address of str:

This is the disassembly of the function:



Try volatile int a = 0, b = 0;

I tried volatile as well and it did not work

I have also attempted to manually refresh the memory viewer using the refresh button, but unfortunately, it did not resolve the issue

I observed now that when I define the int variable globally, it updates correctly in the memory viewer. However, when the int variable is defined locally, the memory viewer does not reflect the changes

@James can you find out which register holds this variable? And check whether that register is updated accordingly to your ++? It looks like the value is not stored on the stack, but is kept in local register instead ..

Can you show the disassembly of your function?

@NateEldredge I've added the disassembly of the function to the post

What is the content of the memory at 0x20009ff0 - 4?

@Jib I had a look at that as well,, also 0. My assumption is that the address of the variable "a" shown in the watch viewer represents where that variable would typically be stored in RAM if the compiler decided to allocate space for it there. So the local variables (a and b) probably never went to RAM.

@James the assembly code shows that the variable is written to RAM (c.f.: str asm instruction). Dumb question but .. did you try to refresh the memory portion you are looking at? It may just be that the IDE does not continuously refreshes the RAM content rendered through the UI ..

@Jib Yes, I have tried to update the memory area manually but nothing happened. However the memory viewer works with the global variable correctly (refreshes correctly), but not with local variables a and b.

@James What is the value of sp and r7 registers? Do they point somewhere around the memory you are watching +/- 8?

@Jib yes sp is: 0x20009fe8 and r7 is 536911848

@James The assembly code shows that the variable a is stored at r7 + 4, so 0x20009ff0 and this is the memory address you are watching. I would suggest you try to attach to the debugger and execute the gdb command x/1w 0x20009ff0 to see what is the 4-bytes content at that address.

it shows the value 6: x/1w 0x20009ff0
0x20009ff0: 6, which is the expected value

When it comes to getting down & dirty with debugging, peripherals, memory or inline asm, using "PC-like" IDEs have never worked well in my experience. These IDEs are usually designed by people who don't have a clue about hardware-related programming. Have you tried to view the trace?

As per the investigations, it seems the issue is neither related to the MCU, the debugger nor the compiler. The issue is rather IDE-related. Indeed, the IDE does not render the monitored memory region in "real time" when a local scope variable gets changed.
Major investigation steps:

look into the assembly code in order to find out potentially unwanted optimizations (even if the flag -O0 was given) and obtain explanations of the observed behavior. This has confirmed the monitored variable is supposed to be properly written in RAM upon each increment operation (thanks to the str assembly instruction).

verify the sp (stack pointer) and r7 registers to find out potentially invalid monitored location. This has confirmed you are looking at the proper location: r7 + 8 (which is also the memory address given by &a so no surprise here).

try to read the RAM memory from a direct GDB command x/1w 0x20009ff0. This has confirmed the RAM memory at this address (&a) holds the current value of a.



Thank you for the Answer. But the IDE does render the monitored memory region for global variables in real time.

Also when allocating local variables in the memory, it will be shown in the memory viewer and works as expected
